# How to select descendant element of clicked element

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Sorry guys.. stupid question.. But cannot seem to get this to work..

```
<td width='17px;' id='".$line["line_id"]."' class='expandable'>
    <i class='icons-toggle-down icons-black' title='Toggle purchase/deliveries..'></i>
</td>
```

and

```
$('.expandable').on('click', function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+id+'.data_line').toggle();
    if ($('#'+id+'.expandable').hasClass('icons-toggle-down'))
        $('#'+id+'.expandable > i').removeClass('icons-toggle-down').addClass('icons-toggle-up');
    else
        $('#'+id+'.expandable > i').removeClass('icons-toggle-up').addClass('icons-toggle-down');
});
```

When the td is pressed ('.expandable') the data_line toggles fine.. but the class icon does not. (font awesome toggle-up and toggle-down)

I am pussled - and it is probably sooo simple ;-)

Comment: just to be clear.. because your js suggests otherwise, do you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: My suggestion would be to add an id to the <i> tag that you can relate to the parent td. Something like <i id='icon".$line["line_id"]."' class='icons-toggle-down icons-black' title='Toggle purchase/deliveries..'></i> Then you can just reference that directly. Looks like you are trying to reference the id of the <i> but it doesn't have one in your example.

Comment: Your HTML is non-conforming to standards (use double quotes), and you're choice of ID is "*interesting*" to be gentle :-) I'd consider some refactoring if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer by dramatically simplifying. See if this helps.

```
$('.expandable').click(function () {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icons-toggle-down icons-toggle-up');
});
```

I'm not sure where `data_line` is, but that's probably a simple addition.

Comment: If you're in the business of dramatically simplifying, at least do `$('i', this)`

Comment: I don't like to simplify to the extent that my scripts are less readable for the novice.

Comment: So instead you choose to advocate bad practices with pointless overhead? SO is about people learning good practices. Besides, [`jQuery(selector [,context])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is the 1st option in the API - not something "for advanced users".

Comment: You're *more than welcome* to downvote and provide an alternative answer. You're not as welcome to take impolite shots at another volunteer developer's approach to teaching.

Comment: @Amit As the docs say, `$(selector, context)` expands internally to `$(context).find(selector)` so if one of them has pointless overhead then it's the former.

Comment: @Juhana, isherwood - I was under the impression jQuery was passing the parameters to Sizzle verbatim - but apparently it does not. I wasn't going to downvote anyway, I only downvote wrong answers (see the tooltip "*This answer is not useful*"), not ones I find imperfect (not the case here though).